# Multiple images in mat-card

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

So I have a `mat-tab-group` which in turn displays a single `mat-card` for each tab. Each card represents a hotel room.

I would like to somehow display several images in the image part of the mat-card, as a gallery of sorts. Are there any ways to do this?

Here's my current HTML template:

```html
<mat-card class="example-card">
  <mat-card-header>
    <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
    <mat-card-title>{{room.name}}</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>${{room.price}} por noche</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
  <mat-card-content>
    <p>
      {{room.details}}
    </p>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-raised-button>Book</button>
    <button mat-button>Share</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mat-card-image` directive can be applied to other elements besides `img`. It is used for nothing more than stretching the item to full width. So you could create a component that provides your 'gallery' experience, and use that instead of the `img`:

```
<mat-card class="example-card">
  <mat-card-header>
    <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
    <mat-card-title>{{room.name}}</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>${{room.price}} por noche</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <my-image-gallery mat-card-image></my-image-gallery>
  <mat-card-content>
    <p>
      {{room.details}}
    </p>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-raised-button>Book</button>
    <button mat-button>Share</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

Or just use your component and handle sizing yourself - don't bother with the directive.